# Turn bathymetry into elevation in arcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcscene, bathymetry

My raster is in depth of bathymetry however when this is shown in 3D it reverses the elevation making the deepest points the highest in elevation and the shallowest points the deepest. This makes a trough look like a mountain when displayed in ArcScene. The data is in distance from the ship not in elevation from the sea bed, is it possible to reverse the data? How would I solve this?

Comment: Just multiply the values with -1

Comment: To complement Martin's answer you can use the [Times tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Times/009z0000009p000000/).